# Oracle, merge tables, insert missing values while increasing id

Tags: oracle, merge, sql-insert

I have two tables, one with values (FACT table), that I'm trying to merge one column into a key/value table (FACT_ATTRIBUTE table). The key is a number, and the value is a varchar2. The FACT_ATTRIBUTE table already has some entries in it. I am trying to write a package procedure that merges in new entries. We are trying to do away with triggers and sequences. I have a bit of SQL that selects entries not already in the table, but I am struggling with how to create the index key value. The key should just be one greater than the current max.

For example, say the FACT_ATTRIBUTE table already has entries up to key 5. A new entry "value 6" comes in. The insert for the key/value would be (6, "value 6") into FACT_ATTRIBUTE.

Here is where I am at:

```
INSERT INTO FACT_ATTRIBUTE (
        KEY, VALUE
    )
    VALUES(
    (SELECT (MAX(KEY) + 1) FROM FACT_ATTRIBUTE),
    (SELECT DISTINCT ENTRY
    FROM FACT fact_table
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT 1 FROM FACT_ATTRIBUTE fa
        WHERE fa.VALUE = fact_table.ENTRY
    ))
    );
```

The problem is obvious, the inner select grabs multiple elements, while the insert is single value. One constraint is that it cannot crash on null (if there are no new values). Is there a good way to accomplish this? My SQL skills are not the sharpest. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For starters, your query seems reversed, it seems like you are entering a numeric value into the value, and a string into the key, whereas in your description you've described the table the other way around (numeric for key and string for value).
Is that on purpose or is there a mistake in the query?

Comment: Thank you, had them reversed but the query still doesn't work

Comment: That comment was not meant to solve your problem, but rather to understand the structure of your data (which was not that clear when reading your question). I've posted a solution as an answer to your question, see if that helps you out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution that got me to what I needed.

```
DECLARE
max_id  NUMBER;
BEGIN

--If no value, start with 1
SELECT NVL(max(fa.FACT_ATTRIBUTE), 1) 
INTO max_id
FROM FACT_ATTRIBUTE fa;

INSERT INTO FACT_ATTRIBUTE (KEY, VALUE)
SELECT max_id + ROWNUM, DATA
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT f.DATA
    FROM FACT f
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM FACT_ATTRIBUTE fa
        WHERE fa.VALUE = f.DATA
    ) 
    AND f.DATA IS NOT NULL
);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might solve your problem is converting your insert statement from values to select. Try this -

```
 INSERT INTO FACT_ATTRIBUTE (
        KEY, VALUE
    )
    SELECT max(key) over (partition by value) + 1 as key_max, f.entry
    FROM (
          SELECT f.entry, fa.value
          FROM fact_table f
          LEFT OUTER JOIN fact_attribute fa
          ON f.entry = fa.value)
    WHERE fa.value is null;
```

It might need a little syntax polish cause I haven't had a server to check this on, but the gist seems right to me - using a left outer join to query all of the entries not existing in FACT_ATTRIBUTE and attaching the current maximum value in the table + 1.